# ActiveStorage - has_one_attached ignores service option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

In my Ruby on Rails 6.1.3.2 application, I'm trying to `has_one_attached` `service` option to upload one of the model attachments to the separate S3 bucket.
Here is how my `storage.yml` looks like:

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_I'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  region: us-east-2
  bucket: <%= ENV['AWS_BUCKET'] %>

amazon_logos_images:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_I'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  region: us-east-2
  bucket: <%= ENV['AWS_LOGOS_BUCKET'] %>
```

In my `production.rb` I have the following Active Storage configuration:

```
config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

My Logo model looks like this:

```
class Logo < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image, service: :amazon_logos_images
end
```

Unfortunately, when I create a new Logo record, the image is uploaded to the `amazon` bucket instead of `amazon_logos_images`. Any idea why the `service` option is ignored by the `has_one_attached` method?

Answer (score 0):

If you come from 6.0:

> If our project is already using Active Storage and when we upgrade to Rails 6.1, we should run rake app:update to make sure service_name column is added to the internal ActiveStorageBlob model.

https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/02/03/rails-allows-configure-service-for-attachments-to-activestorage.html

Otherwise check that `AWS_LOGOS_BUCKET` is properly being populated (i.e. is not the wrong bucket)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using direct upload? If it is, [6.1 can't support direct uploads to multiple services](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38957), you need to upgrade to [7.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v7.0.0).